# Tridion transforms type HTML Component into iframe

Tags: 2011, publishing, cme, dd4t, content-manager

I am using for the first time Tridion and I've noticed while I was trying to create an HTML type Component it was added to the Page as an `IFrame`.

Not sure why this happens, can you help please?

Comment: Welcome to Tridion StackExchange, can you **edit** your question and provide a bit more details on your question? Since while it may be clear to you what a type HTML Component is, it might not be so clear to everybody else here. It helps if you try to describe as much relevant information as possible, and if you are unsure about the terminology, screenshots can help too.

Comment: Please self answer your question and accept that answer or delete your question in that case

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The solution was to check the option Don't show by iFrame.

Comment: I hope you realize that this is part of the implementation and not a product feature?  I love the information design, BTW...  a field called "*Don't* show by iFrame:" with a single checkbox called "yes". Brilliant! :-)  I guess the information designer was an Apple fanboy? ;-)

Comment: Well, it's not always easy with such Boolean settings. Consider how we handle `IsOffline:False` in Topology Manager as "Marked Online" in the UI with a "Yes" value. :-P I have my own preferences on how to (content) model options like this. See posts on [schema fields](http://www.createandbreak.net/2012/09/scalable-schema-fields.html), [feature-based CMS designs](http://www.createandbreak.net/2013/10/feature-driven-cms-development-part-1.html), or an [example for Robot settings](http://www.createandbreak.net/2014/04/managing-robots-meta-tags.html). tl;dr: Opt for Categories instead of Booleans.

Comment: @RickPannekoek :))))))